# ¿Como llamar a xml estando en la carpeta Lib\xml?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

Realizando un ejercicio que empieza con el siguiente código:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

me dice al ejecutarlo que no encuentra el módulo.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Python27\xml1.py", line 1, in 
>       import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>       File "C:\Python27\xml.py", line 1, in 
>       import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>       ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree

El módulo existe en la carpeta Lib\xml\etree. 
¿Me falta quizás tenerlo instalado, que no solo alojado?
¿lo estoy llamando de una manera incorrecta?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python al resolver los import **busca primero el módulo en tu directorio de trabajo actual**, si no lo encuentra se va a la biblioteca estándar.

Un módulo llamado `xml.py` o paquete llamado `xml` ocasionará que intentará realizar el import desde aquí y no desde la biblioteca estándar. Debes cambiar el nombre de tu módulo o paquete a otra cosa.

Deberias agregar la estructura de tu proyecto (carpetas y ficheros que lo componen), es muy posible que la causa sea esta. No tienes que instalar nada, `xml` pertenece a la biblioteca estándar.

Edición: si tu problema se debe a lo anterior es posible que tengas que borrar también el `xml.pyc` generado.

Comment: Pues tenias toda la razón del mundo. 
Había algún que otro archivo, con el nombre xml y diversas extensiones, pero hasta que no he borrado o cambiado el último no ha querido funcionar.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: correcto, uno de los archivos borrados es xml.pyc.